# I don't know how to send an array over socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

The client reads a number, sends it to the server which finds its divisors, then the server sends the divisosr back to client which prints them.

```
int main(){

int s;

struct sockaddr_in server,client;
int l, conn;

s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (s < 0){
    printf("Error on creating the server.");
    return 1;
}

memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
server.sin_port = htons(1234);
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

if (bind(s,(struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
    printf("Eroare la bind.");
    return 1;
}

listen(s,5);

l = sizeof(client);
memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));

while (1){
    uint16_t n, array[10], arraytosend[10];
    conn = accept(s,(struct sockaddr *) &client,&l);
    recv(conn, &n, sizeof(n), MSG_WAITALL);
    n = ntohs(n);

    int d, i=0;
    for (d=2; d<=n/2; d++){
        if ( n % d == 0){
            arraytosend[i] = htonl(array[d]) ;
            i++;
        }
    }
    send (conn, &array, sizeof(array), 0);
    close(conn);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
int main(){
uint16_t n, array[10], arrayrec[10];

struct sockaddr_in server;

int c;

c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (c < 0){
    printf("Eroare la creare socket client.");
    return 1;
}

memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
server.sin_port = htons(1234);
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

if (connect(c, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server))< 0){
    printf("Eroare la conectare.");
    return 1;
}

printf("Give a number: ");
scanf("%hu", &n);

n = htons(n);
send(c,&n, sizeof(n),0);

recv(c, &array, sizeof(array), MSG_WAITALL);
int p=0;
p = htons(p);
for (p=0; p<10; p++){
    array[p] = ntohl(arrayrec[p]);
    printf("%hu", array[p]);
}
close(c);
```

}

When I'm running the server, then the client, it prints : 0000000000

Could somebody help me, please ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: You cannot send anything larger than one byte over a TCP stream.  What protocol on top of TCP are you using?

Comment: Straight off, the result returned by recv() is being ignored :((